# Monotouch: How to display the image in interface builder

Tags: image, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

I Created a monotouch project, add add new files: images/abcd.png(build action:content) into my project. when open the mainUI.xib, In xcode(4.2) Interface Builder design-time, I  manually set the image property with the value "images/abcd.png", but it won't show up until run time.

I know this is a known limitation of MonoDevelop and Interface Builder, but I want to use the image as a background pic to layout my UI in design-time , how can I do?

Environment: XCode4.2+MontoDevelop2.8.6.4+Montotouch 5.2

Comment: I believe that XCode expects all images to be in the root folder

Comment: Jason is correct. All images need to be in the root directory.

Comment: thanks to Jason&jstedfast: yes, now I put the image to the root directory, but all the image&program file in a same folder, it's chaotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in MonoDevelop go `project options -> iPhone Application -> Advanced`
add image to `Icon files` section.
select image in design time, then you will see image at run time.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I mean how can I see the image on the design-time in IB, not at run time.